# Why do i have '?' and 'M' in the class folder Xcode 4?

Tags: ios4, xcode4, cocos2d-iphone

Do not really understand how to ask this question so i added a picture below. My question is why I have '?' and and 'M' to the right?

Also, what should i do with it?

I am currently doing tutorial in Cocos2D.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/SCM/SCM.html) (the table under Section `Keep Track of Your Files’ SCM Status` ).

```
Badge   SCM Status

M        Locally modified

?        Not under source control
```

and there's a few more.